# DLL's not updated when deploying to testing environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, web-applications

I created a new assembly name for one of my projects and must update my DLL files to reflect that. In Visual Studio I can clean the solution and then rebuild to do this locally. From there I must deploy my solution to a server for testing. When I deploy, the DLL's are not being updated on the server and I cannot figure out what is going on. In my build definition I do have 'Clean Workspace' set to all, so I thought it should update.

The solution is under source control and the DLL files are included in the bin.

I can also copy them manually, but I am not sure how to view the DLL files on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: How you are publishing your site to your server?

Comment: Make sure you creating a new release in octopus deploy or else it will keep deploying the same files.